# Get elements from lists if two strings appear in a certain order

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sublist

Let's say I have the following list of lists

```
lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]
```

I need to extract the lists where `A` appears and then `C` appears, not taking into account the other letters that might be between them.

Thus, the result must be something like

```
res=[['ACAC'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['ABBC']]
```

I could implement a for loop inside another for loop that goes inside each lists and then iterates over every string, and sees if `A` appears and `C` appears, but I am a little confused on how to maintain the order of apparition, that is, that `A` appears before `C`

Comment: Should `'CAC'` be included in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]

out = [[i] for (i, ) in lst if 'A' in i and 'C' in i and i.index('A') < i.index('C')]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['ACAC'], ['AACC'], ['BACB'], ['ABBC']]
```

---

Or using `re`:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'A.*C')

lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]

out = [[i] for (i, ) in lst if r.search(i)]
print(out)
```

---

Solution from @OlvinRoght:

```
lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]
res = [i for i in lst if len(i[0]) > i[0].find('C') - i[0].find('A') > 0]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

extending  @andrej regex solution

```
import re
r = list(filter(lambda x: [i for i in x if re.findall('A.*C', i)], l))
```

A non-regex, solution

```
def find_patt(lis):
    res =[]
    for sublis in lis:
        tmp =[]
        for ele in sublis:
            if ('A' in ele) and ('C' in ele):
                if ele.index('A')<len(ele)-ele[::-1].index('C'):
                    tmp.append(ele)
        if tmp!=[]:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp =[]
    return res

lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC'], ['CAC']]

print(find_patt(lst))
# [['ACAC'], ['AACC'], ['BACB'], ['ABBC'], ['CAC']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: (Edited to account for lists that do not contain chars 'A' or 'C')

```
lst=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]

res = []

for lst_inner in lst:
    if ('A' in lst_inner[0] and 'C' in lst_inner[0] and
        lst_inner[0].find('A') < lst_inner[0].find('C')):
        
        res.append(lst_inner)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hello world")

inputList=[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]
print(inputList)

matchingCharactersInOrderList = ["A","C"]
filteredList=[]

for subList in inputList:
    tempStringToMatchOrder=""
    tempStringToMatchOrder = tempStringToMatchOrder.join(subList)
    if  matchingCharactersInOrderList[0] in tempStringToMatchOrder:
        partitionedString = tempStringToMatchOrder.partition(matchingCharactersInOrderList[0])[2]
        if matchingCharactersInOrderList[1] in partitionedString:
            filteredList.append(subList)
#matching = [s for s in lst if ("A" in s)]

print(filteredList)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
lst =[['AAAB'],['ACAC'],['CABA'],['AACC'],['BACB'],['BCAA'],['CBAA'],['ABBC']]
res = []

def check(list_string):
    index1=0
    index2=0
    for letters in list_string:
        if letters == 'A':
            index1 = list_string.index(letters)
            break
    for letters in list_string:
        if letters =='C':
            index2 = list_string.index(letters)
            break
    if index1 < index2:
        return True
    elif index1 > index2:
        return False
    else:
        return False


for x in lst:
    string = x[0]
    string_splitted = list(string)
    if check(string_splitted):
        res.append(x)
print(res)
```

Comment: suggestion, in your code `index1=list_string.index('A'), index2=list_string.index('C')`, so here using for loop is unnecessary, since you are iterating to string and want to get the minimum of `A` index and max of `C` index, I suggest you use `enumerate()` function as `str.index(element)` will always provide the index of first occuerence of the element